# React native find closest location From user location

Tags: location, react-native, react-native-ios

i have array of location (cities) and i want to find from my current location nearest city from that array of location .

I'd like to test the distance between my user's locations against my array to see which location is the closest. How do I do this?

Comment: You use google direction api

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty good documentation on how to calculate distance between two geo-location with Javascript examples that you can find [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

> **Calculate distance, bearing and more between Latitude/Longitude points**
>
> This page presents a variety of calculations for lati­tude/longi­tude
> points, with the formulæ and code fragments for implementing them.
>
> All these formulæ are for calculations on the basis of a spherical
> earth (ignoring ellipsoidal effects) – which is accurate enough* for
> most purposes… [In fact, the earth is very slightly ellipsoidal; using
> a spherical model gives errors typically up to 0.3%1 – see notes for
> further details].

Assuming you have an array with the geo-locations of the cities, you can loop through and calculate the distance against the current location of the user you get with the [Geolocation API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html) of react-native.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the data as an array of array/ object. For the demo code I am using array of array.

```
const cities = [
 ["city1", 10, 50, "blah"],
 ["city2", 40, 60, "blah"],
 ["city3", 25, 10, "blah"],
 ["city4", 5, 80, "blah"] 
];

deg2Rad = (deg) => {
  return deg * Math.PI / 180;
}

pythagorasEquirectangular = (lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) => {
  lat1 = this.deg2Rad(lat1);
  lat2 = this.deg2Rad(lat2);
  lon1 = this.deg2Rad(lon1);
  lon2 = this.deg2Rad(lon2);
  const R = 6371;
  const x = (lon2 - lon1) * Math.cos((lat1 + lat2) / 2);
  const y = (lat2 - lat1);
  const d = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y) * R;
  return d;
}
nearestCity = (latitude, longitude) => {
 let mindif = 99999;
 let closest;

 for (index = 0; index < cities.length; ++index) {
  const dif = this.pythagorasEquirectangular(latitude, longitude, cities[index][1], 
    cities[index][2]);
    if (dif < mindif) {
    closest = index;
    mindif = dif;
 }
 return cities[closest]
}
```

or something like this. Also you can get the current location using [Geolocation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html).
Call `nearestCity(lat, lon)` with your current lat, lon.
Hope this helps.

Comment: what about PythagorasEquirectangular

Comment: Updated the pythagorasEquirectangular function. Sorry about that.
mindif is just a local variable.

Comment: Does pythagorasEquirectangular return distance in meters? @SubhenduKundu

Answer (score 0):

This method has already been used in a previous reaction, unfortunately it was not suitable for React Native. I have edited the code so that it works on React Native.

The code is as follows:

```
cities = [
     ["city1", 10, 50, "blah"],
     ["city2", 40, 60, "blah"],
     ["city3", 25, 10, "blah"],
     ["city4", 5, 80, "blah"] 
    ];
     nearestPlace = null;

    deg2Rad = (deg) => {
      return deg * Math.PI / 180;
    }

    pythagorasEquirectangular = (lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) => {
      lat1 = this.deg2Rad(lat1);
      lat2 = this.deg2Rad(lat2);
      lon1 = this.deg2Rad(lon1);
      lon2 = this.deg2Rad(lon2);
      const R = 6371;
      const x = (lon2 - lon1) * Math.cos((lat1 + lat2) / 2);
      const y = (lat2 - lat1);
      const d = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y) * R;
      return d;
    }
    nearestCity = (latitude, longitude) => {
     let mindif = 99999;
     let closest;


     for (let index = 0; index < this.cities.length; index++) {
      const dif = this.pythagorasEquirectangular(latitude, longitude, this.cities[index][1], 
        this.cities[index][2]);
        if (dif < mindif) {
        closest = index;
        mindif = dif;
        }

      }
      this.nearestPlace = closest

    }
```

So when you then `this.nearestCity (yourLat, yourLon)` you will find the result in `this.nearestPlace`.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use other package to calculate distance, like https://github.com/cmoncrief/geodist

Then you can calculate distance between two point by code

```js
var geodist = require('geodist')

var dist = geodist({lat: 41.85, lon: -87.65}, {lat: 33.7489, lon: -84.3881})
console.log(dist)           
// => 587
```